# what should I do...? I cannot install avro on 14.4

Tags: ibus

Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 2,919 B in 22s (129 B/s)
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
mahfuz@mahfuz-desktop:~$

Answer (score 1):

Open up your terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./"
wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ibus-avro-trusty
```

Now logout and log back in or restart Ubuntu.

Click in the `En` icon in the top panel.

[image]

In the Text Entry Settings, click the `+` icon to add a new keyboard. find `Avro` from there and add that.

[image]

Now switch between English and Avro keyboard by pressing `Super + Space` (super means the key with windows/ubuntu logo)

[image]

You are done!

For the error `E: Unable to lock the administration directory`, please restart your computer once.

Hope it'll help.